# Get p-value for group mean difference without refitting linear model with a new reference level

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, hypothesis-test

When we have a linear model with a factor variable `X` (with levels `A`, `B`, and `C`)

```
y ~ factor(X) + Var2 + Var3
```

The result shows the estimate `XB` and `XC` which is differences `B - A` and `C - A`. (suppose that the reference is `A`).

If we want to know the p-value of the difference between `B` and `C`: `C - B`,
we should designate B or C as a reference group and re-run the model.

Can we get the p-values of the effect `B - A`, `C - A`, and `C - B` at one time?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for linear hypothesis test by check p-value of some linear combination of regression coefficients. Based on my answer: [How to conduct linear hypothesis test on regression coefficients with a clustered covariance matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40120677/4891738), where we only considered sum of coefficients, I will extend the function `LinearCombTest` to handle more general cases, supposing `alpha` as some combination coefficients of variables in `vars`:

```
LinearCombTest <- function (lmObject, vars, alpha, .vcov = NULL) {
  ## if `.vcov` missing, use the one returned by `lm`
  if (is.null(.vcov)) .vcov <- vcov(lmObject)
  ## estimated coefficients
  beta <- coef(lmObject)
  ## linear combination of `vars` with combination coefficients `alpha`
  LinearComb <- sum(beta[vars] * alpha)
  ## get standard errors for sum of `LinearComb`
  LinearComb_se <- sum(alpha * crossprod(.vcov[vars, vars], alpha)) ^ 0.5
  ## perform t-test on `sumvars`
  tscore <- LinearComb / LinearComb_se
  pvalue <- 2 * pt(abs(tscore), lmObject$df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE)
  ## return a matrix
  form <- paste0("(", paste(alpha, vars, sep = " * "), ")")
  form <- paste0(paste0(form, collapse = " + "), " = 0")
  matrix(c(LinearComb, LinearComb_se, tscore, pvalue), nrow = 1L,
         dimnames = list(form, c("Estimate", "Std. Error", "t value", "Pr(>|t|)")))
  }
```

Consider a simple example, where we have a balanced design for three groups `A`, `B` and `C`, with group mean 0, 1, 2, respectively.

```
x <- gl(3,100,labels = LETTERS[1:3])
set.seed(0)
y <- c(rnorm(100, 0), rnorm(100, 1), rnorm(100, 2)) + 0.1

fit <- lm(y ~ x)
coef(summary(fit))

#             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) 0.1226684 0.09692277  1.265631 2.066372e-01
#xB          0.9317800 0.13706949  6.797866 5.823987e-11
#xC          2.0445528 0.13706949 14.916177 6.141008e-38
```

Since `A` is the reference level, `xB` is giving `B - A` while `xC` is giving `C - A`. Suppose we are now interested in the difference between group `B` and `C`, i.e., `C - B`, we can use

```
LinearCombTest(fit, c("xC", "xB"), c(1, -1))

#                         Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(1 * xC) + (-1 * xB) = 0 1.112773  0.1370695 8.118312 1.270686e-14
```

Note, this function is also handy to work out the group mean of `B` and `C`, that is `(Intercept) + xB` and `(Intercept) + xC`:

```
LinearCombTest(fit, c("(Intercept)", "xB"), c(1, 1))

#                                 Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(1 * (Intercept)) + (1 * xB) = 0 1.054448 0.09692277 10.87926 2.007956e-23

LinearCombTest(fit, c("(Intercept)", "xC"), c(1, 1))

#                                 Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
#(1 * (Intercept)) + (1 * xC) = 0 2.167221 0.09692277 22.36029 1.272811e-65
```

---

**Alternative solution with `lsmeans`**

Consider the above toy example again:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(fit, spec = "x", contr = "revpairwise")

#$lsmeans
# x    lsmean         SE  df    lower.CL  upper.CL
# A 0.1226684 0.09692277 297 -0.06807396 0.3134109
# B 1.0544484 0.09692277 297  0.86370603 1.2451909
# C 2.1672213 0.09692277 297  1.97647888 2.3579637
#
#Confidence level used: 0.95 
#
#$contrasts
# contrast estimate        SE  df t.ratio p.value
# B - A    0.931780 0.1370695 297   6.798  <.0001
# C - A    2.044553 0.1370695 297  14.916  <.0001
# C - B    1.112773 0.1370695 297   8.118  <.0001
#
#P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

The `$lsmeans` domain returns the marginal group mean, while `$contrasts` returns pairwise group mean difference, since we have used "revpairwise" contrast. Read p.32 of [`lsmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf) for difference between `"pairwise"` and `"revpairwise"`.

Well this is certainly interesting, as we can compare with the result from `LinearCombTest`. We see that `LinearCombTest` is doing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`glht` (general linear hypothesis testing) from `multcomp` package makes this sort of multiple hypothesis test easy without re-running a bunch of separate models. It is essentially crafting a customized contrast matrix based on your defined comparisons of interest.

Using your example comparisons and building on the data @ZheyuanLi provided:

```
x <- gl(3,100,labels = LETTERS[1:3])
set.seed(0)
y <- c(rnorm(100, 0), rnorm(100, 1), rnorm(100, 2)) + 0.1

fit <- lm(y ~ x)

library(multcomp)
my_ht <- glht(fit, linfct = mcp(x = c("B-A = 0",
                             "C-A = 0",
                             "C-B = 0")))
```

`summary(my_ht)` will give you the adjusted p-values for the comparisons of interest.

```
#Linear Hypotheses:
#           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#B - A == 0   0.9318     0.1371   6.798 1.11e-10 ***
#C - A == 0   2.0446     0.1371  14.916  < 1e-10 ***
#C - B == 0   1.1128     0.1371   8.118  < 1e-10 ***
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I haven't looked at `lsmeans` besides reading through your answer. How do you do you import the console result?

Comment: I like `glht` because I can pass things like `linfct = mcp(x = "Dunnett")` or linfct = mcp(x = "Tukey") which is nice if I have a lot of levels to work through.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the library `car`, and use the function `linearHypothesis` with the parameter `vcov`.

Set this as the `variance-covariance` matrix of your model.

The function takes formulas or a matrix to describe the system of equations that you would like to test.